# handle single quote and double quote in jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

I have created one link from foreach loop in that I am showing one link with different parameters in jquery function

```
<?php
  foreach ($questions as $row) {
    if (!empty($row['url_ImageName'])) {
       $url_ImageName = $row['url_ImageName'];      
    }else{
    $Paragraph =  $row['Paragraph'];
    }
    ?>
      <a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('<?php echo $url_ImageName; ?>','<?php echo $Paragraph; ?>')">Show Details</a>
    <?php
}  ?>
```

```js
function question_details(url_ImageName,Paragraph){
 if (url_ImageName != '') 
 {
  $(".exam-slideout .question-details img").attr("src",url_ImageName);    
 }
 if (Paragraph != '') 
 {
  $('.exam-slideout .question-details div').html(Paragraph);
 }
 
}
```

in that first link which is created this:

```
<a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="onclick="question_details('','“ What the deuce is it to me ” ? he interrupted impatiently: “ you say that we go round the sun. If we went round the moon it would not make a pennyworth of difference to me or to my work.”')">Show Details</a>
```

and the second link which is created this:

```
<a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('','Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn't smear.')">Show Details</a>
```

in that, I have facing an issue with single quotes and double quotes.

to resolve this issue I have a try

```
$Paragraph = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['Paragraph']);
```

But still function is not working with syntax error.

can anybody help me in this.

Comment: Have you tried [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a escape character (\) before the `'` used in the middle of the string like:

```
<a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('','Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn\'t smear.')">Show Details</a>
```

Alternative using Template Literals:

```
<a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('',`Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn't smear.`)">Show Details</a>
```

You can learn more about [Working with Strings in JavaScript](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript).

Comment: shows me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes) on the `$Paragraph` variable, this will escape `'` into `\'`. It will also escape `"`, so be a bit wary of it.

```php
<a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('<?php echo $url_ImageName; ?>', '<?php echo addslashes($Paragraph); ?>')">Show Details</a>
```

Alternatively, replace all occurrances of `'` to `\'` using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace).

```php
<a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('<?php echo $url_ImageName; ?>', '<?php echo str_replace("'". "\'", $Paragraph); ?>')">Show Details</a>
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/IFLnY

Comment: with this, it creates this link <a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('','Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn\'t smear.')">Show Details</a> but still function doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? "Not working" is not very helpful or descriptive, we can't do much but guess without the actual errors. Check your console.

Comment: I have checked my console it shows me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: for this link <a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('','Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn't smear.')">Show Details</a>

Comment: You haven't added `addslashes()` or replaced the quote. See the quote in `doesn't`, that breaks the string.

Comment: Yes I added that and it shows me: onclick="question_details('','Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn\'t smear.')"

Comment: I have add <a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('<?php echo $url_ImageName; ?>','<?php echo str_replace("'", "\'", $Paragraph); ?>')">Show Details</a> code and it shows me <a href="#" id="opendetail" onclick="question_details('','Complete drying is essential before adding the sealant so that the paint doesn\\'t smear.')">Show Details</a> result wih this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list